# Money class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, unit-testing

I have recently created the `Money` class with a helper class `Currency`. What do you think about the following code? I created unit tests for my class using very nice `pytest` library.

Is it a good idea to put code tests in the `if __name__ == '__main__'` or should I always use dedicated libraries like `unittest` and `pytest`?

Is it okay to make `self` attribute assignment depend on the another attribute assignment, for example let's suppose we have an assignment `self.amount = default_value` depending on whether `self.precision` is defined first, where `self.amount` is property setter that uses `self.precision`?

How can I simplify repeating decorators code like I have in the `test_money.py`?

If I am going to gather exchange rate info from the Internet, should I still use `namedtuple` or use `dataclasses`?

Thanks

`money.py`:

```
import functools
from decimal import Decimal
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Currency:
    name: str
    symbol: str
    exchange_rate: Decimal

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({self.name!r}, {self.symbol!r}, {self.exchange_rate!r})"


@functools.total_ordering
class Money:
    def __init__(self, amount: Decimal, currency: Currency, precision: int = 2):
        self._amount = amount
        self.precision = precision
        self.currency = currency

    @property
    def amount(self) -> Decimal:
        return self._amount.quantize(Decimal("10") ** -self.precision)

    @amount.setter
    def amount(self, value: Decimal) -> None:
        self._amount = value

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.amount} {self.currency.symbol}"

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({self.amount!r}, {self.currency!r})"

    def __add__(self, other):
        if self.currency != other.currency:
            raise ValueError(f"cannot add two {self.__class__.__name__} instances: "
                             "different currency property")
        return Money(self.amount + other.amount, self.currency)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        if self.currency != other.currency:
            raise ValueError(f"cannot subtract two {self.__class__.__name__} instances: "
                             "different currency property")
        return Money(self.amount - other.amount, self.currency)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        if self.currency != other.currency:
            raise ValueError(f"cannot multiply two {self.__class__.__name__} instances: "
                             "different currency property")
        return Money(self.amount * other.amount, self.currency, self.precision)

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        if self.currency != other.currency:
            raise ValueError(f"cannot divide two {self.__class__.__name__} instances: "
                             "different currency property")
        return Money(self.amount / other.amount, self.currency, self.precision)

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        if self.currency != other.currency:
            raise ValueError(f"cannot add two {self.__class__.__name__} instances: "
                             "different currency property")
        self.amount += other.amount
        return self

    def __isub__(self, other):
        if self.currency != other.currency:
            raise ValueError(f"cannot subtract two {self.__class__.__name__} instances: "
                             "different currency property")
        self.amount -= other.amount
        return self

    def __imul__(self, other):
        if self.currency != other.currency:
            raise ValueError(f"cannot multiply two {self.__class__.__name__} instances: "
                             "different currency property")
        self.amount *= other.amount
        return self

    def __idiv__(self, other):
        if self.currency != other.currency:
            raise ValueError(f"cannot divide two {self.__class__.__name__} instances: "
                             "different currency property")
        self.amount /= other.amount
        return self

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.currency != other.currency:
            raise ValueError(f"cannot compare two {self.__class__.__name__} instances: "
                             "different currency property")
        return self.amount < other.amount

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.currency != other.currency:
            raise ValueError(f"cannot compare two {self.__class__.__name__} instances: "
                             "different currency property")
        return self.amount == other.amount
```

`test_money.py`:

```
import pytest
from example_shop.shop.money import Currency, Money
from decimal import Decimal
from typing import Optional


def money_euro(amount: str, precision: Optional[int] = None) -> Money:
    if precision is None:
        return Money(Decimal(amount), Currency("Euro", "EUR", Decimal("4.52")))
    return Money(Decimal(amount), Currency("Euro", "EUR", Decimal("4.52")), precision)


def money_usd(amount: str, precision: Optional[int] = None) -> Money:
    if precision is None:
        return Money(Decimal(amount), Currency("American dollar", "USD", Decimal("4.17")))
    return Money(Decimal(amount), Currency("American dollar", "USD", Decimal("4.17")), precision)


@pytest.mark.parametrize("price1,price2,expected",
                         [(money_usd("1.5"), money_usd("1.2"), money_usd("2.7")),
                          (money_usd("2.7"), money_usd("1.3"), money_usd("4.0")),
                          (money_usd("2.700"), money_usd("1.3"), money_usd("4.00000")),
                          (money_usd("1.5", 4), money_usd("1.5", 3), money_usd("3", 4)),
                          (money_usd("-1.5", 4), money_usd("3", 5), money_usd("1.5", 5))])
def test_money_add_the_same_currency(price1, price2, expected):
    assert price1 + price2 == expected


@pytest.mark.parametrize("price1,price2,expected",
                         [(money_usd("1.5"), money_usd("1.2"), money_usd("0.3")),
                          (money_usd("2.7"), money_usd("1.3"), money_usd("1.4")),
                          (money_usd("2.700"), money_usd("1.3"), money_usd("1.40000")),
                          (money_usd("1.5", 4), money_usd("1.5", 3), money_usd("0", 4)),
                          (money_usd("1.5", 4), money_usd("3", 5), money_usd("-1.5", 5))])
def test_money_subtract_the_same_currency(price1, price2, expected):
    assert price1 - price2 == expected


@pytest.mark.parametrize("price1,price2,expected",
                         [(money_usd("1.5"), money_usd("1.2"), money_usd("1.8")),
                          (money_usd("2.7"), money_usd("1.3"), money_usd("3.51")),
                          (money_usd("2.700"), money_usd("1.3"), money_usd("3.51000")),
                          (money_usd("0", 4), money_usd("1.5", 3), money_usd("0", 4)),
                          (money_usd("1.5", 4), money_usd("-3", 5), money_usd("-4.5", 5))])
def test_money_multiply_the_same_currency(price1, price2, expected):
    assert price1 * price2 == expected


@pytest.mark.parametrize("price1,price2,expected",
                         [(money_usd("1.5"), money_usd("1.2"), money_usd("1.25")),
                          (money_usd("2.7"), money_usd("1.3"), money_usd("2.08")),
                          (money_usd("2.700"), money_usd("1.3"), money_usd("2.08000")),
                          (money_usd("0", 4), money_usd("1.5", 3), money_usd("0", 4)),
                          (money_usd("1.5", 4), money_usd("-3", 5), money_usd("-0.5", 5))])
def test_money_divide_the_same_currency(price1, price2, expected):
    assert price1 / price2 == expected


@pytest.mark.parametrize("price1,price2",
                         [(money_usd("1.5"), money_euro("1.2")),
                          (money_euro("1.2"), money_usd("1.5")),
                          (money_usd("1.5", 4), money_euro("1.2", 5)),
                          (money_euro("1.2", 4), money_usd("1.5", 5))])
def test_money_add_the_different_currency(price1, price2):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        assert price1 + price2


@pytest.mark.parametrize("price1,price2",
                         [(money_usd("1.5"), money_euro("1.2")),
                          (money_euro("1.2"), money_usd("1.5")),
                          (money_usd("1.5", 4), money_euro("1.2", 5)),
                          (money_euro("1.2", 4), money_usd("1.5", 5))])
def test_money_subtract_different_currency(price1, price2):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        assert price1 - price2


@pytest.mark.parametrize("price1,price2",
                         [(money_usd("1.5"), money_euro("1.2")),
                          (money_euro("1.2"), money_usd("1.5")),
                          (money_usd("1.5", 4), money_euro("1.2", 5)),
                          (money_euro("1.2", 4), money_usd("1.5", 5))])
def test_money_multiply_different_currency(price1, price2):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        assert price1 * price2


@pytest.mark.parametrize("price1,price2",
                         [(money_usd("1.5"), money_euro("1.2")),
                          (money_euro("1.2"), money_usd("1.5")),
                          (money_usd("1.5", 4), money_euro("1.2", 5)),
                          (money_euro("1.2", 4), money_usd("1.5", 5))])
def test_money_divide_different_currency(price1, price2):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        assert price1 / price2


@pytest.mark.parametrize("price1,price2,expected",
                         [(money_usd("1.5"), money_usd("1.2"), money_usd("2.7")),
                          (money_usd("2.7"), money_usd("1.3"), money_usd("4.0")),
                          (money_usd("2.700"), money_usd("1.3"), money_usd("4.00000")),
                          (money_usd("1.5", 4), money_usd("1.5", 3), money_usd("3", 4)),
                          (money_usd("-1.5", 4), money_usd("3", 5), money_usd("1.5", 5))])
def test_money_add_in_place_the_same_currency(price1, price2, expected):
    result = price1
    result += price2
    assert result == expected


@pytest.mark.parametrize("price1,price2,expected",
                         [(money_usd("1.5"), money_usd("1.2"), money_usd("0.3")),
                          (money_usd("2.7"), money_usd("1.3"), money_usd("1.4")),
                          (money_usd("2.700"), money_usd("1.3"), money_usd("1.40000")),
                          (money_usd("1.5", 4), money_usd("1.5", 3), money_usd("0", 4)),
                          (money_usd("1.5", 4), money_usd("3", 5), money_usd("-1.5", 5))])
def test_money_subtract_in_place_the_same_currency(price1, price2, expected):
    result = price1
    result -= price2
    assert result == expected


@pytest.mark.parametrize("price1,price2,expected",
                         [(money_usd("1.5"), money_usd("1.2"), money_usd("1.8")),
                          (money_usd("2.7"), money_usd("1.3"), money_usd("3.51")),
                          (money_usd("2.700"), money_usd("1.3"), money_usd("3.51000")),
                          (money_usd("0", 4), money_usd("1.5", 3), money_usd("0", 4)),
                          (money_usd("1.5", 4), money_usd("-3", 5), money_usd("-4.5", 5))])
def test_money_multiply_in_place_the_same_currency(price1, price2, expected):
    result = price1
    result *= price2
    assert result == expected


@pytest.mark.parametrize("price1,price2,expected",
                         [(money_usd("1.5"), money_usd("1.2"), money_usd("1.25")),
                          (money_usd("2.7"), money_usd("1.3"), money_usd("2.08")),
                          (money_usd("2.700"), money_usd("1.3"), money_usd("2.08000")),
                          (money_usd("0", 4), money_usd("1.5", 3), money_usd("0", 4)),
                          (money_usd("1.5", 4), money_usd("-3", 5), money_usd("-0.5", 5))])
def test_money_divide_in_place_the_same_currency(price1, price2, expected):
    result = price1
    result /= price2
    assert result == expected


@pytest.mark.parametrize("price1,price2",
                         [(money_usd("1.5"), money_euro("1.2")),
                          (money_euro("1.2"), money_usd("1.5")),
                          (money_usd("1.5", 4), money_euro("1.2", 5)),
                          (money_euro("1.2", 4), money_usd("1.5", 5))])
def test_money_add_in_place_the_different_currency(price1, price2):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        result = price1
        result += price2
        assert result


@pytest.mark.parametrize("price1,price2",
                         [(money_usd("1.5"), money_euro("1.2")),
                          (money_euro("1.2"), money_usd("1.5")),
                          (money_usd("1.5", 4), money_euro("1.2", 5)),
                          (money_euro("1.2", 4), money_usd("1.5", 5))])
def test_money_subtract_in_place_different_currency(price1, price2):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        result = price1
        result -= price2
        assert result


@pytest.mark.parametrize("price1,price2",
                         [(money_usd("1.5"), money_euro("1.2")),
                          (money_euro("1.2"), money_usd("1.5")),
                          (money_usd("1.5", 4), money_euro("1.2", 5)),
                          (money_euro("1.2", 4), money_usd("1.5", 5))])
def test_money_multiply_in_place_different_currency(price1, price2):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        result = price1
        result *= price2
        assert result


@pytest.mark.parametrize("price1,price2",
                         [(money_usd("1.5"), money_euro("1.2")),
                          (money_euro("1.2"), money_usd("1.5")),
                          (money_usd("1.5", 4), money_euro("1.2", 5)),
                          (money_euro("1.2", 4), money_usd("1.5", 5))])
def test_money_divide_in_place_different_currency(price1, price2):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        result = price1
        result /= price2
        assert result

@pytest.mark.parametrize("price1,price2,expected",
                         [(money_euro("1.23"), money_euro("4.56"), True),
                          (money_euro("1.5"), money_euro("1"), False),
                          (money_usd("-2"), money_usd("0"), True),
                          (money_euro("0"), money_euro("0"), False)])
def test_less_than_the_same_currency(price1, price2, expected):
    assert (price1 < price2) == expected


@pytest.mark.parametrize("price1,price2,expected",
                         [(money_euro("1.23"), money_euro("4.56"), False),
                          (money_euro("1.5"), money_euro("1"), False),
                          (money_usd("-2"), money_usd("0"), False),
                          (money_euro("0"), money_euro("0"), True)])
def test_equal_the_same_currency(price1, price2, expected):
    assert (price1 == price2) == expected


@pytest.mark.parametrize("price1,price2",
                         [(money_usd("1.23"), money_euro("4.56")),
                          (money_euro("1.5"), money_usd("1"))])
def test_less_than_different_currency(price1, price2):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        assert price1 < price2


@pytest.mark.parametrize("price1,price2",
                         [(money_usd("1.23"), money_euro("4.56")),
                          (money_euro("1.5"), money_usd("1"))])
def test_equal_different_currency(price1, price2):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        assert price1 == price2
```

Comment: Your code is very concise and I like it. You clearly made effort to reduce repetition. But you still haven't eliminated repetition completely. You have currency type check that raises exceptions in each of the dunder methods that does something, the message is almost identical, except for some words related to method name. You have to extract it as a separated helper method and have the other methods call it to do the checking, with the method type as an argument.

Comment: And then this doesn't make sense at all, money of different currency systems can be compared, added and subtracted. That is why we have currency exchange rate, just convert one currency to the other using the exchange rate and do it as normal.

Comment: But the ability to multiply (and therefore divide) money is pure nonsense, it doesn't make sense at all. Two dollars times two is four dollars. What is two dollars times **two dollars**? ***Four dollars squared***? The other number needs to be unitless.

Comment: What do you think about make `Money` and `Currency` a named tuples and define function `convert_currency`?

Comment: I can't offer anymore advices on code, I only know how to make code more concise and efficient, efficiency isn't a problem here, and your code is very concise except for the one function you failed to extract. But you do have two major logical failures that need to be fixed.

Comment: What currency should the result be if we add or subtract `Money(Decimal(x), currency)` to/from `Money(Decimal(y), currency2)`?

Comment: Should `__eq__` compare if two `Money` instances have only the same amount and do automatic conversions of different currency or just compare if `amount` and `currency` are equal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146444/discussion-between---and-lester).

Comment: Approve of fixed-point `Decimal`. Most financial institutions and tax preparers in the U.S. keep track of transactions to four decimal places (milrays), to guarantee that they will always round correctly to the nearest cent.

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος most of that needs to be moved to an answer

Answer (score 3):

The `Currency` class is simple and nice.

Thank you for the unit tests! They are helpful.

---

```
    exchange_rate: Decimal
```

I have no idea what that means,
and the comments, docstrings, narrative do not enlighten me.

Is that a rate to convert the given currency to Yen, to Dinar,
to something else?
That is, are we measuring a US Dollar -> Yen rate?
A Euro -> Yen rate?

Are you *sure* this attribute is really needed here?
Consider removing it.
Currency conversion can be a complex topic,
for example the time and place of conversion make a difference.
It probably belongs in a separate module.

---

I am uncomfortable with rounding in the `Money` class.
Also, I wouldn't mind seeing both

- `Money(Decimal(1/8), usd)` and
- `Money('0.125', usd)`

behave identically, for the sake of the caller's convenience.
That is, I think of a "money" as a "decimal" quantity,
so asking me to use it in a different way doesn't quite feel right.
Perhaps `Currency` should always offer a helper
that constructs a new `Money` ?

I appreciate that we consistently round to `precision` on the way out,
e.g. with expressions like `invoice.amount` or `str(invoice)`.
But I'm not sure how an app developer is supposed to reason
about a quantity like this:

```
invoice = Money(Decimal('.12'), usd)
invoice += Money(Decimal('.135'), usd)
```

At this point `str(invoice)` will reveal pennies,
despite having precision to mils on the inside.

(BTW, fun fact, '.125' --> .12 while '.135' --> .14, which
is correct round-to-even behavior.)

I think my objection boils down to discomfort
with tracking two distinct quanitities:

- public `invoice.precision == -2` above, yet
- `invoice._amount.as_tuple().exponent == -3`

I don't see a motivating use case for this in the
narrative nor in the test suite.
I think I recommend abandoning the redundant `invoice.precision`
attribute entirely.

I'm not happy that an app developer can silently misuse
the ctor and misuse the setter.
There's no checking, no duck typed operation,
which immediately blows up when e.g. a `str`
is passed in rather than a `Decimal`.
Simplest way to fix? I recommend that you
assign `Decimal(amount)` and assign `Decimal(value)`,
silently "fixing" it on the way in.
Consider raising an error if someone foolishly
passes in a float, e.g. `Money(1/8, usd)` or
`Money(0.10, usd)` probably won't do what developer intended,
and he will thank you for immediately pointing that out.

---

I like the "currencies must match!" rule for addition.
Let the app developer do an approximate conversion rate
calculation if he really wants to add one dollar to one euro.

It's odd that `__sub__` doesn't just `__add__` with
flipped sign. That would let you code the "must match!"
test just once.

What's going on with mul & div ?!?
That's just crazy.
Unconditionally `raise` an error and be done with it.
You export `.amount` and that suffices.

Nice use of `total_ordering` !

---

In the `money_euro` test helper,
special treatment for `precision` of `None`
is a bit odd.
Consider defining a `kw` dict which is
either empty or contains a numeric value,
and finish the `Money` call with `**kw)`

Consider defining `eur` and `usd`
in the test suite or perhaps in the money module.

---

Tests are the one place where "copy-n-paste is OK".
But I found that the repeated pasting of four
money pairs distracted me from easily reading
what mattered, which is the *differences*
between the various tests.
Assign the list to a variable
so you can concisely refer to it.

Consider writing a
[hypothesis](https://pypi.org/project/hypothesis)
test for this module.

Comment: Should I compare in `__eq__` and `__lt__` only if `self.amount` is equal/less than `other.amount` and raise an error if objects have a different currencies or do conversions to common currency, for instance USD and compare accordingly objects?

Comment: Tell the app developer that comparing apple to orange, or dollar to euro, is `raise TypeError("not supported")` . Otherwise we need to worry about buy-side vs sell-side conversion rate, documentation, and lots of fractional digits. There's no motivating use case, so just bail, don't even go there. The app developer can access `invoice.amount` to convert currencies to his heart's content.

Comment: Do you think that I should in the constructor assign to `self.amount = Decimal(amount)`? I did a comparison `if not isinstance(amount, str): raise TypeError(...)`, and made type annotation `amount: str`. Is it a good way?

Comment: The concern I gave voice to was that ctor and setter might assign `self._amount = ".125"` if an app developer mistakenly passed that in. You _document_ that caller must supply `amount: Decimal`, and I recommend you _enforce_ that `self._amount` shall always be a Decimal. We call this a Class Invariant. Documenting something more permissive, like `amount: str | Decimal`, would be fine. I also mentioned that we should probably `raise` if app developer mistakenly passes in a float. I'm just trying to anticipate how folks would misuse the module, and how hard the bugs are to find.

Comment: I have answered my own question. Is the mine proposed code better?

Comment: Wow. Less code, yet the refactor still passes all tests, nice. Recommend you assign a list of two or four Money pairs to a variable, to make the tests more concise.

Comment: I corrected unit tests code. Anyway, thank you for help. I'm going to further experimenting with Python :-)

Comment: I would have assumed `exchange_rate : Decimal` is the exchange rate of the currency that the amount is denominated in. If that is not what it represents, OP definitely needs to explain it.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers (and comments that should be answers) have covered most of my concerns.

This does not follow how most locales would prefer to format their currency:

```
f"{self.amount} {self.currency.symbol}"
```

Instead use `locale` support, which (among other things) will give you your international currency name, proper formatting, grouping etc. Also, you should either freeze your currency dataclass or use `NamedTuple` instead. As a demonstration,

```py
import locale
from contextlib import contextmanager
from decimal import Decimal
from functools import lru_cache
from numbers import Number
from pprint import pprint
from typing import NamedTuple, Iterator, Any


class Currency(NamedTuple):
    value_eur: Decimal
    display_locale: str

    @contextmanager
    def use_locale(self) -> Iterator:
        """This is not thread-safe"""
        old_locale = locale.getlocale(category=locale.LC_MONETARY)
        try:
            locale.setlocale(category=locale.LC_MONETARY, locale=self.display_locale)
            yield
        finally:
            locale.setlocale(category=locale.LC_MONETARY, locale=old_locale)

    @property
    @lru_cache(maxsize=1)
    def localeconv(self) -> dict[str, Any]:
        """A dictionary of int_curr_symbol, currency_symbol, etc. For details see
        https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.localeconv
        """
        with self.use_locale():
            return locale.localeconv()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.localeconv['int_curr_symbol']

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({self.display_locale!r}, {self.value_eur!r})"

    def format(
        self, val: Number,
        symbol: bool = True, grouping: bool = True, international: bool = False,
    ) -> str:
        with self.use_locale():
            return locale.currency(val=val, symbol=symbol, grouping=grouping,
                                   international=international)

    def __truediv__(self, other: 'Currency') -> Decimal:
        return self.value_eur / other.value_eur


cad = Currency(display_locale='en_CA', value_eur=Decimal(0.69680235))
inr = Currency(display_locale='ta_IN', value_eur=Decimal(0.011331307))
pprint(inr.localeconv)
print(cad.format(23_400_000))
print(inr.format(23_400_000))
print(
    cad.format(1, international=True), 'is worth',
    inr.format(cad/inr, international=True),
)
```

```
{'currency_symbol': '₹',
 'decimal_point': '.',
 'frac_digits': 2,
 'grouping': [],
 'int_curr_symbol': 'INR',
 'int_frac_digits': 2,
 'mon_decimal_point': '.',
 'mon_grouping': [3, 2, 0],
 'mon_thousands_sep': ',',
 'n_cs_precedes': 1,
 'n_sep_by_space': 1,
 'n_sign_posn': 4,
 'negative_sign': '-',
 'p_cs_precedes': 1,
 'p_sep_by_space': 1,
 'p_sign_posn': 4,
 'positive_sign': '',
 'thousands_sep': ''}
$23,400,000.00
₹ 2,34,00,000.00
CAD1.00 is worth INR61.49
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit made to code:

`money.py`:

```
import functools
from decimal import Decimal
from typing import NamedTuple


class Currency(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    symbol: str

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}(name={self.name!r}, symbol={self.symbol!r})"


@functools.total_ordering
class Money:
    def __init__(self, amount: Decimal, currency: Currency):
        if isinstance(amount, float):
            raise TypeError("amount should not be float")
        self.amount = Decimal(amount)
        self.currency = currency

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.amount} {self.currency.symbol}"

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}(amount={self.amount!r}, currency={self.currency!r})"

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.currency != other.currency:
            raise ValueError("comparison between different currencies is not supported")
        return self.amount < other.amount

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.currency != other.currency:
            raise ValueError("comparison between different currencies is not supported")
        return self.amount == other.amount


EUR = Currency("Euro", "EUR")
USD = Currency("American dollar", "USD")
```

`test_money.py`:

```
import pytest
from example_shop.shop.money import Money, EUR, USD
from decimal import Decimal


@pytest.mark.parametrize("price1,price2,expected",
                         [(Money(Decimal("1.23"), EUR), Money(Decimal("4.56"), EUR), True),
                          (Money(Decimal("1.5"), EUR), Money(Decimal("1"), EUR), False),
                          (Money(Decimal("-2"), USD), Money(Decimal("0"), USD), True),
                          (Money(Decimal("0"), EUR), Money(Decimal("0"), EUR), False)])
def test_less_than_the_same_currency(price1, price2, expected):
    assert (price1 < price2) == expected


@pytest.mark.parametrize("price1,price2,expected",
                         [(Money(Decimal("1.23"), USD), Money(Decimal("4.56"), USD), False),
                          (Money(Decimal("1.5"), EUR), Money(Decimal("1"), EUR), False),
                          (Money(Decimal("-2"), EUR), Money(Decimal("0"), EUR), False),
                          (Money(Decimal("0"), USD), Money(Decimal("0"), USD), True)])
def test_equal_the_same_currency(price1, price2, expected):
    assert (price1 == price2) == expected


@pytest.mark.parametrize("price1,price2",
                         [(Money(Decimal("1.23"), EUR), Money(Decimal("4.56"), USD)),
                          (Money(Decimal("1.5"), USD), Money(Decimal("1"), EUR))])
def test_less_than_different_currency(price1, price2):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        assert price1 < price2


@pytest.mark.parametrize("price1,price2",
                         [(Money(Decimal("1.23"), EUR), Money(Decimal("4.56"), USD)),
                          (Money(Decimal("1.5"), USD), Money(Decimal("1"), EUR))])
def test_equal_different_currency(price1, price2):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        assert price1 == price2
```

Comment: Better you edit your question, instead of posting this as answer :)

Comment: I'll remember next time

Comment: @BillalBegueradj, I know you're trying to be helpful, and I thank you for that. On SO sometimes appending "I found it!" to a question is most helpful, and sometimes a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) works best. But CodeReview is slightly different. I direct your attention to [item 6](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour): "_After an answer is posted, you must not edit your question to invalidate any advice._" If OP revises code in the question, such edits will soon be reverted. The idea is so folks reading a year later will see the original text + suggestions.

Comment: @J_H thank you for the information

Comment: Thanks for posting this code.  It's a good idea to summarise which changes you made, and why - a self-answer ought to review the code, just like any other answer.

Comment: @TobySpeight this is not an answer (?)